# jsPDF watermark image over text

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I'm using the jsPDF plugin but I'm having a problem, I can have a different number of pages with different content, and I'm putting two watermarks. The problem is that sometimes the text is extrapolating the page size and the image is overlapping the text, in addition to the text breaking when moving to the next page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjmbn.png)

There is text underneath the logo in the footer, and the header logo should take up the full width of the page.

```
function downloadPdf(tipo) {
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var evento_id = $("#evento_id").val();
        var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#visaoPdf");        
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });        
        $.ajax({
                'url' : '{{ route("route") }}',
                'type' : 'POST',
                'data' : {evento_id : evento_id, tipo: tipo},
                'success' : function(data) {     
                    var dados = data;
                    doc.html(dados, {
                        callback: function(doc) {
                            doc.p
                            doc.addFileToVFS('Montserrat-Medium-normal.ttf');
                            doc.addFont('Montserrat-Medium-normal.ttf', 'Montserrat-Medium-normal', 'normal');
                            doc.setFont('Montserrat-Medium-normal', 'normal');     
                            doc.setFontSize(28);
                            doc = addWaterMark(doc, tipo);
                            doc.save(tipo + evento_id +'.pdf');
                        },
                        x: 15,
                        y: 20,
                        width: 170,
                        height: 250,
                        windowWidth: 750
                    });
                }
        });


function addWaterMark(doc, tipo) {
        var totalPages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = '/img/logo-pdf.png';
        img2.src = '/img/rodape-pdf.png';
        for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            doc.setPage(i);
            doc.addImage(img1, 'PNG', doc.internal.pageSize.width - 50, 5, 45, 14);
            if(tipo != 'visaogeral'){
                doc.addImage(img2, 'PNG', 8, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 30, 200, 25);
            }            
            // doc.setTextColor(150);
            // doc.text(50, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 30, 'Watermark');
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

I would like to know if it is possible to place a padding on the image, or put it to occupy the entire width of the page, and place it as a non-floating element.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question so it is entirely in English or try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  your question has now been voted open.